# How do I place a crosshair inside the circular cursor?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, interface-design

I know that if you press CAPSLOCK it changes the cursor into a crosshair, but that way I can't see the size of my circle.

Is there a way to have both things activated?

Comment: Have you even looked in the preferences?

Comment: It's a fair question, often with Adobe, things like this are controlled through keyboard shortcuts, menus or some button or option in one of the many many button windows.

Answer (score 1):

Scott's correct. Look in preferences, then find cursors and you should see something like this:

[image]